# How to implement input based filtering in Dev X grid version 9.0

Tags: c#, .net, filter, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to build a edit mode filtering in wpf devX grid. This functionality is inbuilt in v13 but I am on v9.

Scenario : 
I have a grid which by default shows a checkbox based / list based filter dropdown. I want to replace it with a textbox based filter where user can enter any input including regex and it does the filtering. This needs to be done only for selective columns not for all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update to recent versions. Forget dinosaur stuff from 5 years ago.

Comment: can not update to recent version due to other limitations. I need a solution with 9.0 only.

Comment: well, its a huge code base shared by multiple apps. So replacing anything is not as trivial job. Instead of getting into details of why we can not replace is, I would be more interested in any hints towards solution.

Comment: post the relevant code and XAML.